# Дайте краткий ответ, как это сверстать?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дайте краткий план того, как это сверстать на boostrap 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень легко. Представь себе сетку, а это наложено поверх [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Ну и слева например блок на 4, потом 1 пустая клетка, и остальные 7 один блок а в нем в линию Ваш текст навигации или что там ( что хотите )